# An example of a field extension where every polynomial has a root but is not algebraically closed

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F\subset E$ be an *algebraic* extension of fields and suppose that every polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ has a root in $E$. Is it possible that $E$ is not algebraically closed?

Note that such an example must necessarily be of prime characteristic since over char $0$, $E$ is necessarily algebraically closed. Proof:

Let $g(x) \in E[x]$ be a polynomial with a root $\alpha$ (after fixing an algebraic closure of $E$). Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ and let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$. By the primitive element theorem, $L=F[\beta]$ and if $h(x)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\beta$, it has some root $\gamma \in E$. Since $F[\beta] = F[\gamma]$, this shows that $L\subset E$.

In particular, if we are looking for counterexamples, we would like $L$ to not be a primitive extension.

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/721608/11619) a duplicate?

Comment: I believe you are correct!