# Question about the proof of: $E/k$ is algebraic of characteristic zero. Every $f(x)\in k[x]$ has a root in $E$. Then $E$ is algebraically closed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

**Question**

Let $k\subset E$ be an algebraic extension of fields of characteristic zero. Assume that every non-constant polynomial $f(x)\in k[x]$ has a root in $E$. Show that $E$ is algebraically closed.

**Answer**

I was following one of the answers given in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721608/if-e-f-is-algebraic-and-every-f-in-fx-has-a-root-in-e-why-is-e-algebr), namely the last one. The answers follows like:

"First take $f\in k[x]$. Then as characteristic is zero $Spl(f)=k(\alpha)$. Then $m_{\alpha,k}(x)$, minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $k[x]$, has a root in $E$. Thus, $E$ contains a copy of the splitting field of $f$."

I didn't understand how the last sentence holds. Thanks in advance...

Also related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285330/if-every-polynomial-in-kx-has-a-root-in-e-is-e-algebraically-closed).

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has a root, say $\beta$, in $E$. But then $k(\alpha) $ is isomorphic to $k(\beta) \subseteq E$ and $k(\beta) $ is a splitting field of $f$ as well.

Comment: Ohh that was the fact I was missing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The result is called Gilmer's theorem. You should have a look at Keith Conrad's notes here: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/algclosure.pdf