# Is the "set" of all algebraic extensions a set?

Tags: set-theory, extension-field

Consider a field $K$. Now, consider the class of all algebraic extensions of $K$. Is this a set? Since I think it isn't, how to prove it isn't?

If the class were of all extensions of $K$, I think I could argue with Zorn's Lemma to get a maximal element and enlarge it by taking the field of fractions of the polynomials with coefficients in that maximal element (proving, thus, that it is a not a set), but I can't repeat this argument for algebraic extensions. So, what to do ?

Comment: Any ZF object (set) can be a member of an algebraic extension.

Comment: I am more than almost sure that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621944/proof-of-existence-of-algebraic-closure-too-simple-to-be-true/

Comment: "For instance, the field of all algebraic numbers is an infinite algebraic extension of the rational numbers." - Wikipedia.  So there's a maximal element of any chain $\Bbb{Q} \subset \dots$.  Let $\Bbb{Q}'$ be the maximal element.  It's possible that $\Bbb{Q}' \subsetneq $ your field of fractions yet is isomorphic to it.