# Is dependent choice what one must use in this step of Artin's construction of the algebraic closure?

Tags: field-theory, set-theory, extension-field, axioms

In both Lang's *Algebra* and Atiyah, MacDonald, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, the following construction of the algebraic closure is atributed to Artin:
[image]
(Atiyah, MacDonald, exercises of Chapter 1.)

I wanted to make a question regarding the step “repeat the construction with $K_1$ in place of $K$, obtaining a field $K_2$, and so on.” Implicitly, the argument here is claiming that we can find a chain of field extensions
$$
K=K_0\subset K_1\subset K_2\subset \cdots
$$ such that, for all $j\geq 0$, the extension $K_j\subset K_{j+1}$ is algebraic and every polynomial of $K_j[x]$ has a root in $K_{j+1}$.
My question is: what is the precise set-theoretic tool that allows one to get such a chain? At the beginning I would have said that it is [dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice).

[image]

But if so, what is the set $X$ that we are applying $\mathsf{DC}$ to? It seems that $X$ must be the collection of all algebraic field extensions of $K$. But the problem is that this collection is a [proper class](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/622101/394668).

(I should say perhaps that I have no background of set theory at all. One day I found out about what $\mathsf{DC}$ is and, after that, I realized that it is actually what one must use in certain things that are sometimes justified by mathematicians “by applying induction.”)

Comment: Although the collection of all algebraic field extensions of $K$ is a proper class, you can restrict attention to the *set* of algebraic field extensions of $K$ which happen to have underlying set in $V_\kappa$ for some fixed sufficiently large $\kappa$. This is a standard trick throughout set theory ("Scott's trick").

Comment: @NoahSchweber What are $\kappa$ and $V_\kappa$?